# Display value from foreign Key in datagridView C# wpf

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datagridviewcolumn, material-design-in-xaml

I'm creating an app using wpf and c#.
I have a datagridview wherever I want to display all data from a SQL Server Database.

I have two tables

```
public class Class1{
     public int Id{get; set;}
     public string Name1 {get; set;}
}

  public class Class2{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name2 {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("Class1")]
     public int Class1FK {get;set;}
     public Class1 Class1 {get;set;}
 }
```

Here is my wpf code

```
      <DataGrid
            Name="data_grid"
            Canvas.Left="10"
            Canvas.Top="79"
            Margin="2,62,2,0"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            materialDesign:DataGridAssist.CellPadding="13 8 8 8"
            materialDesign:DataGridAssist.ColumnHeaderPadding="8"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserSortColumns="True"
            ColumnHeaderHeight="NaN"
            Cursor="Hand"
            FontSize="14"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Class2}" >               

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
                <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Name 2" Binding="{Binding Name2}"/>
                <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Name 1" Binding="{Binding Class1.Name1}" />
              <DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

But when I run my app the `name2` doesn't display

Comment: You are binding something named `Class1`. If that is an instance of `Class1` then it does not have a `Class2` member - it only has `Id` and `name1`.

Comment: I think I didn't write correctly. The binding source is Class2

Comment: Does the `Name2` binding work? Because your class has a lowercase "n" and your binding has an uppercase "N". Also, consider better names for properties, it is confusing to use the class name as the property name.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see it. But how to display the value of the Name1 of the Class1 in the same datagrid?